# libmesos-1.3.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: mesos

I have installed mesos-1.3.0 from sources on ubuntu 16.04 (mint 18.2). When I try to start mesos-master with next command:

```
mesos-master --ip="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" --work_dir="/tmp/mesos-master1" --zk=zk://zookeeper1:4181,zookeeper2:5181,zookeeper3:6181/mesos --quorum=1 --log_dir=/tmp/mesos/master/log --cluster=YAMYAM
```

I'm getting the error below:

```
mesos-master: error while loading shared libraries: libmesos-1.3.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that library "libmesos-1.3.0.so" could not found by mesos-master command. There are 2 options to solve this issue:

**Option 1**: try to update mesos shared libraries with the next command:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

**Option 2:** If option 1 doesn't solve your problem try the next steps for updating location of missed mesos libraries:

1. locate "libmesos-1.3.0.so" result: `/usr/local/lib/libmesos-1.3.0.so`
2. update environment variable "LD_LIBRARY_PATH":

   ```
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
   ```
3. run the failed command again

Comment: You may actually want to prepend `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with the gathered value instead of possibly overwriting it.